# How to add string to a url in php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a random string using a php function I found here

```
<?php function generateRandomString($length = 12) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $randomString;
}

$randomString = generateRandomString(); ?>
```

I have a form

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/results/">
    <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Enter height">
    <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Enter weight">
    <input type="submit" id="export">
</form>
```

When you click submit it takes you to the .com/results/ page but i am trying to change /results/ to the random string from the `generateRandomString` function and still show the content that would have been shown on the results page

To do this so far i have tried adding this jQuery under the form

```
$("#export").click(function(){
    url = $("#form").attr("action");
    url = url.replace("/results/",<?php echo $randomString ?>);
    $("#form").attr("action", url).submit();
});
```

but that still doesn't work. Does anyone know how another way i could do this please?

Thank you

the php file below-

```
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<?php function generateRandomString($length = 12) {
    $characters =     '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$randomString = generateRandomString();
?>

<form method="post" id="form" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/results/">
    <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Enter height">
    <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Enter weight">
    <input type="submit" id="export">
</form>

<script>
$("#export").click(function(){
  url = $("#form").attr("action");
  url = url.replace("/results/",<?php echo $randomString ?>);
  $('#form').attr('action', url).submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: try
url = url.replace("/results/","<?php echo $randomString ?>");

Comment: @AlexOdenthal that still takes you to /results/. It does give an error saying $ is not defined in console, but I put in script tags (it's in php file) and added jQuery library - don't know why it still say that

Comment: /results/ is a wordpress page that gets its contents from results.php file. I have it kind of working now!! It will return mydomain.com/random BUT it 404 and says the page isnot found. Any idea how i can send content from results.php to the new url?

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not return a value, use return statement:

```
 function generateRandomString($length = 12) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: even with return it still doesnot replace, i have added the php code so you can see

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

<?php
 function generateRandomString($length = 12) {
    $characters =     '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$randomString = generateRandomString();
?>
  <form method="post" id="form" action="google.com/results/">
    <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Enter height">
    <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Enter weight">

</form>
 <input type="submit" id="export">


<script>
$("#export").click(function(event){
  url = $("#form").attr("action");
  url = url.replace("results/","<?php echo $randomString ?>");
  console.log(url);
 //event.preventDefault();
  $('#form').attr('action', url).submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: please see the update, still does not work with return in function

Comment: you have to write php code in java script using " ". So  replace url.replace("/results/",<?php echo $randomString ?>); with url.replace("/results/","<?php echo $randomString ?>");

Comment: I appreicate your help sir, but that still just goes to /results/. i am getting these console errors: GET domain.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js and Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function. Maybe that is causing the problem?

Comment: I executed those code but i didn't get any error . whatever see the update code and run on your server .

Comment: I have it kind of working now thanks to you! it is going to mydomain.com/randomString after i click it, but it says the page isnot found. Do you know how i could still send the content from /results/ page (results.php) to the new url?

Comment: With everytime I read the question again, I think you just want to use url rewrite htaccess mechanism. here is a tutorial for that. https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

It would be very helpful to let us know what you want to achieve with the replacement of the real url part with some random id.